# KeyModifier.SHIFT not working in Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I am new to Sikuli. I need to do Ctrl+Shift+Down in Sikuli.

I have tried:

type(Key.DOWN, KeyModifier.SHIFT + KeyModifier.CTRL)
and
type(Key.DOWN, KeyModifier.SHIFT|KeyModifier.CTRL)

but none of them works.Both produce the same effect as pressing Ctrl+Down.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to some bug, Shift combinations do not work if NumLock is on.
The solution I used was to toggle it using:

```
type(Key.NUM_LOCK)
```

I found the answer here: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/272223

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# Push down keys.
keyDown(Key.CTRL)
keyDown(Key.SHIFT)

type(Key.DOWN)

# Release keys. 
keyUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
type(Key.DOWN, KeyModifier.SHIFT,  KeyModifier.CTRL)
```

Pay attention that i only use "," not "+".